# Implicit declaration of function is invalid in C99

Tags: c, arrays

I am new to C language and I am having a problem that I  really don't understand. I am trying to get an array from another function but when I try to extract the information, it gives me the following warning:

> Implicit declaration of function 'getk_vector_calculation' is invalid in C99
>   Array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal

Here is the code:

```
int k_vector_calculation(int krec[3])

{
    ...

    krec [0] = l*u[0]+m*v[0]+o*[0] ;

    krec [1] = l*u[1]+m*v[1]+o*[1] ;

    krec [2] = l*u[2]+m*v[2]+o*[2] ;

    return k_vector_calculation( &krec[3] ) 

}

int main ()

{

    char krec[3] = getk_vector_calculation(&krec[3]); 

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your `main()` the function you called is `getk_vector_calculation()` <sup>[which is not `k_vector_calculation()`]</sup> and which is not `declared` or `defined` before the usage.

To resolve this,

1. either `#include` the header file containg the declaration of `getk_vector_calculation()` in your sorce file. [Considering `getk_vector_calculation()` is in some other file]
2. or, add a forward declaration of `getk_vector_calculation()` before `main()` and define `getk_vector_calculation()` somewhere.

To know more about implicit declaration, you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2161304/2173917).

---

EDIT:

As others have pointed out, there are *many more* problems in your code snippet. But since the question title is limited to `implicit declaration` error, IMO, this answer should do the needful. The remaining error(s) is(are) altogether a different aspect.

Comment: Pointing out that `char krec[3] = getk_vector_calculation(&krec[3]);` is completely invalid would also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but how should I write it instead?

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of C, functions that had not been declared yet were still able to be called, and it was assumed that they returned `int` and took an unspecified number of arguments. Strictly speaking, in C99, it is not permitted to call a function without declaring it first.

In your case however, you are trying to call a function called `getk_vector_calculation` but you have defined a function called `k_vector_calculation` (no `get` at the beginning).

You are also trying to initialise an array using a function, which is not permitted (in C, functions cannot return arrays). Simply declare the array and call `k_vector_calculation` as a separate statement, e.g.:

```
int krec[3] = {0};
k_vector_calculation(krec);
```

Don't use `&krec[3]` as this points to an invalid location. Use `&krec[0]` to provide the address of the first element in the array, or equivalently just `krec` will do. N.b. also that you declare an array of type `char`, but your function accepts a pointer to `int`, and these types are not compatible. Your function also calls itself unconditionally so there is a guaranteed infinite recursion if the snipped out code does not conditionally return. If your function doesn't need to call itself, and it doesn't return a value of any importance, change the return type to `void` to indicate it has no return value.

Since you are using C99, you can take advantage of using the `static` keyword in your function's parameter declaration:

```
void k_vector_calculation(int krec[static 3])
{
    // ... other code here ...
    krec[0] = l*u[0]+m*v[0]+o*[0];
    krec[1] = l*u[1]+m*v[1]+o*[1];
    krec[2] = l*u[2]+m*v[2]+o*[2];
}
```

The above code declares a function that takes as an argument an array of *at least* 3 `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues, here:

1. As Sourav Ghosh pointed out, you define `k_vector_calculation()`, but then try to call `getk_vector_calculation()`. You have to use the right names.
2. You say you want to "get an array from another function" - you just can't do this in C.
3. You don't show all your code for `k_vector_calculation()`, but as shown, this function will call itself forever, because the last thing it does is to unconditionally call itself again. If you have a recursive function, you need to give it a way to terminate.
4. `&krec[3]` is the address of the fourth element of the array `k`, which is not want you want to be doing, here, especially since your array only contains 3 elements. To refer to the array itself, just use `krec`.
5. `char krec[3] = getk_vector_calculation(&krec[3]);` is invalid for numerous reasons. One, you can't initialize arrays in this way in C. Two, see point (4) for your argument. Three, even if you could initialize arrays this way in C, you'd be trying to pass an uninitialized array to a function, initialize it in there, and then try to initialize your original array with the result. It just makes no sense.
6. You also write your functions to work with an array of `int`, but declare `krec` in `main()` as an array of `char`.

It's not clear what you want `k_vector_calculation()` to do, but you just can't return arrays in C like that. Probably what you want to do is just pass the array to the function, have the function work on in, and return nothing. For instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void k_vector_calculation(int kvec[])
{
    kvec[0] = 1;
    kvec[1] = 2;
    kvec[2] = 3;
}

int main(void)
{
    int kvec[3];
    k_vector_calculation(kvec);

    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {
        printf("kvec[%d] is %d.\n", i, kvec[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```