# How do I get rid of -Wimplicit-function-declaration

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, function-declaration

I've splitted up my C source code into 2 files: `main.c` and `secondary.c` respectively.

```
/* main.c */

#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "secondary.c"

int main ()
{
         extern int my_var;

         my_var = 123;
         print_value ();
         exit (0);
}
```

```
/* secondary.c */

#include <stdio.h>
int my_var;

void print_value ()
{
        printf("my_var = %d\n", my_var);
}
```

I use the following command to compile them:

```
$gcc -Wall main.c secondary.c
```

But in this case I receive the following warning:

```
snowgold@iskhakov-r:~/clang$ gcc -Wall main.c secondary.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:9:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘print_value’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    9 |         print_value();
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Then I decide to include `secondary.c` in `main.c`. To do so, I type `#include "secondary.c"` in `main.c`.

In this case, I get the following error:

```
snowgold@iskhakov-r:~/clang$ gcc -Wall main.c secondary.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccKKRtFc.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `my_var'; /tmp/ccx4HrNG.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccKKRtFc.o: in function `print_value':
secondary.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `print_value'; /tmp/ccx4HrNG.o:main.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What do I do to get rid of `-Wimplicit-function-declaration`?

Comment: Provide a prototype for the function before you call it. `void print_value ();` Normally you'd put that in a header and include that header in files where you use the function.

Comment: [Message "warning: implicit declaration of function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440816/message-warning-implicit-declaration-of-function) and [What does "implicit declaration of function" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161304/what-does-implicit-declaration-of-function-mean) may help as well.

Comment: @RetiredNinja , ah, I forgot about prototypes... Thanks, and if you write your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: To properly declare a function that takes no parameters, use the `void` keyword, e.g. `void print_value(void);` and `int main(void)`. An empty parameter list `()` is only allowed for backwards compatibility with C89 code. Empty parameter lists should never be used in new code.

Comment: ... and don't include `.c` files. @user3386109  Empty parameter lists will be ok in C2x. It'll mean the function takes no arguments, just like it's been used most of the time.

Comment: @TedLyngmo why?

Comment: @RodionIskhakov Because you compile `.c` files individually. Put the declarations in a  header file and include that. That way _many_ `.c` files can include the same header file without getting "multiple definitions..." like you got.

Comment: @TedLyngmo If C2x says that `()` means a function that takes no parameters, then that's not at all like it's been used in the past (at least for function prototypes). A function prototype with an empty parameter list used to mean a function that takes any number of parameters of unspecified types.

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, I know, but I've rarely (never I think) seen it actually used that way. I've seen tons of C code with no parameters (or `void`) in their prototypes and they have always been used as functions that takes no parameters.

Comment: @user3386109 I've checked the C23 standard page on wikipedia, and found the following line: "functions with no arguments listed in the prototype `void foo()` are understood as taking no arguments (see removal of K&R function declarations)"

Comment: @RodionIskhakov Apparently the C standards committee has made yet another bad decision. But you are correct that **if you're using a C23 compiler**, then you can omit the `void` keyword.

Comment: @user3386109 Maybe there is an official C standarts committee site? Because I didn't find one, and I didn't find what "bad decision" has C standarts committee made. Where can I read about it？

Comment: @RodionIskhakov [The international standardization working group for the programming language C](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/) and here's a direct link to [the C2x draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3096.pdf) (ISO/IEC 9899:2023)

Comment: Distinguish between function declarations and function definitions — the latter have a compound statement in braces after the signature; the former usually have a semicolon (or occasionally, but undesirably, a comma) after the signature.  When defining a function, using `function()` does indicate that the function takes no parameters, but it does not provide a prototype for the function unless you're working with C23 or a later standard.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ When declaring a function, using `function()` indicates that nothing is known about the argument list (except that it isn't a variadic function with a signature ending with `, ...)` — those must be declared with a full prototype), again with the caveat that the rules change with C23 or later.  In C23, C finally catches up with C++ — the K&R-style non-prototype function definitions are no longer valid C and empty parentheses in an argument list indicate "no arguments". It will be a while before I regard it as safe to use that — I'll be using `(void)` for another decade or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the first compiler message the compiler does not know how the function `print_value()` used in the module `main.c` is declared when it compiles the module.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include "secondary.c"

int main ()
{
         extern int my_var;

         my_var = 123;
         print_value ();
         exit (0);
}
```

Create a header with the function declaration (prototype) like

```
void print_value( void );
```

and include the header in the both modules.

As for the second message then after including `secondary.c` in `main.c` you have two definitions of the same function in the both modules `main.c` and `secondary.c`. Do not include c midules in each other.

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Also this statement

```
exit (0);
```

is redundant. Remove it.

Also bear in mind that according to the C23 Standard you may not use functions without function prototypes as it was allowed before the C23 Standard.

Comment: Should I really add the `void` keyword as an argument of a function? It still works well without it and send no warnings. Are there any objective reasons?

And why should I remove the `exit (0);` statement? I've read that this statement specifies that the program ended normally and all is well. The `exit` function also perform some tidy-up duties such as closing open files. Using the `exit(0);` or `return 0;` is also specified by GNU coding standart.

Comment: @RodionIskhakov As I have written the new C23 Standard does not allow such declarations. As for the second question when if the control achieves the closing brace of the function main then the effect is the same as if you would place explicitly statement return 0;

Comment: I've checked the C23 standard page on wikipedia, and found the following line: "functions with no arguments listed in the prototype `void foo()` are understood as taking no arguments (see removal of K&R function declarations)"

Comment: @RodionIskhakov void foo(); is not a function prototype. There is nothing known about its parameters.

Comment: @RodionIskhakov From the C23 Standard Draft  "The following documents have been applied to this draft from the January/February 2022 Virtual
Meeting, Parts 1 and 2:" ..."N2841 No Function Declarators without Prototypes"

Comment: @RodionIskhakov I am sorry. You are right "13 For a function declarator without a parameter type list: the effect is as if it were declared with a
parameter type list consisting of the keyword void. A function declarator provides a prototype for
the function" The difference with preceding standards is that early this declaration void foo() meant that nothing is known about function parameters.

Comment: I understand. Благодарю за уделенное время!)

Comment: @RodionIskhakov No at all. We, beginners, should help each other.:)

Comment: Can you also please tell me where did you read that the use of `exit(0);` function is redundant? Because I've read in a book ("The GNU C Programming Tutorial") that "GNU coding standards specify that you should always use `exit` (or `return`) within your main function."

Comment: @RodionIskhakov From the C Standard "5.1.2.2.3 Program termination
1 If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the initial call
to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main
function as its argument;11) reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0. If
the return type is not compatible with int, the termination status returned to the host environment
is unspecified."

Comment: The variable, `my_var`, should also be declared in a header included by both source files, rather than being declared ad hoc inside a function in one file.

Comment: Personally, I regard the "fall off the end of `main()` is equivalent to `return 0;`" rule as an abhorrent piece of special caseism.  It agrees with C++98, but that's all that's good about it (and I regard the decision to allow it in C++ as suspect too).  I always use `return 0;` or `return exit_status;` or something similar at the end of `main()` — I do not regard it as good practice to simply fall off the end of `main()`.  It's a function that returns an `int`; it should return an `int` if you don't call one of the `exit()` family of functions.